# Android - How to handle Dialog during rotation

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

My problem is that my Activity recreate dialog box instance when device is rotated even user clicked Cancel button. Result is that dialog box doesn't dismiss and reappear again when device is rotated.

This is DialogFragment:

```
   public class DistanceDialog extends DialogFragment{



@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.distance_dialog, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}

  }
```

Then, in a Fragment I call dialog :

```
   new DistanceDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "distancedialog");
```

Can you explain me what is the best way of how to handle dialog state between rotation ? Thanks guys!

**UPDATE:**

After many tests I noticed that this problem occurs only in the spinner action. In fact if I call dialog using simple button it works well but if i try to call the dialog box in the spinner listener problem persist.

this is the spinner listener I'm using:

```
          @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long ID){
        switch(pos){
        case 0:
             //DOING SOME STUFF
            break;
        case 1:
             //DOING SOME STUFF

            break;
        case 2:
             new DistanceDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "distancedialog");
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `setDismissMessage` call in `onDestroyView`.

Just set retain instance in `onCreate` or `onCreateDialog`.

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

and change the `onDestroyView` as

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Libin, but I think this not resolve the problem. Please read my update above.